# urlEncoding issue with Swift Odata

Tags: odata, swift4, swift5

Our OData service

```
 {{url}}/odata/GroupMembers?$filter=GroupName eq 'PDL-**-Users-Test'
```

The spaces before and after **eq** is becoming **%2520** upon urlencoding in Swift which is leading to error code 400.

```
odata/GroupMembers?$filter=GroupName%2520eq%2520'PDL-**-Users-Test'
```

Comment: It seems You urlencode Your string two times: `%20` is urlencoded `%2520`

Comment: Could you share the relevant code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My earlier code was,

```
urlComponents.queryItems = [URLQueryItem]()

for (key,value) in parameters {
         let queryItem = URLQueryItem(name: key,
                                         value: "\(value)".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed))            
   }

urlRequest.url = urlComponents.url
```

by removing the following code, it worked.

```
.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
```

Reason being Apple's URLComponents and URLQueryItem does the encoding in Swift.